# Take a txt file from computer and Insert it tableview (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, tableview

I want to take a `txt file` from computer and insert it `tableview`.The contents of the file in the following way;
Country,Capital,Population,Democracy => Of course they are `tablecolumn`.the items should be in order.

How to take txt `file`. How to convert this `file` to `observableList` or is this necessary and finally how to insert `tableview`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample that should get you on your way.  You'll notice I am using Java 8 to read all lines in the file, covert them into a data structure then add that to your table.  Hope this helps.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class SampleApp extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch (args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Collection<CountryData> list = Files.readAllLines(new File("c:/temp/data.txt").toPath())
                        .stream()
                        .map(line -> {
                            String[] details = line.split(",");
                            CountryData cd = new CountryData();
                            cd.setCountry(details[0]);
                            cd.setCapital(details[1]);
                            cd.setPopulation(details[2]);
                            cd.setDemocracy(details[3]);
                            return cd;
                        })
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        ObservableList<CountryData> details = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);

        TableView<CountryData> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<CountryData, String> col1 = new TableColumn<>();
        TableColumn<CountryData, String> col2 = new TableColumn<>();
        TableColumn<CountryData, String> col3 = new TableColumn<>();
        TableColumn<CountryData, String> col4 = new TableColumn<>();

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(col1, col2, col3, col4);

        col1.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().countryProperty());
        col2.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().capitalProperty());
        col3.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().populationProperty());
        col4.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().democracyProperty());

        tableView.setItems(details);

        StackPane sp = new StackPane(tableView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(sp);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }




     private class CountryData {
        StringProperty country = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty capital = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty population = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty democracy = new SimpleStringProperty();
        public final StringProperty countryProperty() {
            return this.country;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getCountry() {
            return this.countryProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setCountry(final java.lang.String country) {
            this.countryProperty().set(country);
        }

        public final StringProperty capitalProperty() {
            return this.capital;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getCapital() {
            return this.capitalProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setCapital(final java.lang.String capital) {
            this.capitalProperty().set(capital);
        }

        public final StringProperty populationProperty() {
            return this.population;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getPopulation() {
            return this.populationProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setPopulation(final java.lang.String population) {
            this.populationProperty().set(population);
        }

        public final StringProperty democracyProperty() {
            return this.democracy;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getDemocracy() {
            return this.democracyProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setDemocracy(final java.lang.String democracy) {
            this.democracyProperty().set(democracy);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. @purring pigeon

Comment: Glad I could help!  The more I work with Java 8 & JavaFX the more impressed I am with the tooling.